# Visual Basic 2010 - Groupbox, Group Event handler

Tags: vb.net, events, handler, groupbox

I have created a groupbox on a Windows form. It has many text boxes (ALL textbox controls). I find myself adding this event handler to each textbox. Is there a way that one event handler could be written to handle every time the user moves from textbox to textbox?
Here is a sample of the current event(s) being handled which works fine.

```
Private Sub CustomerIDTextBox_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CustomerIDTextBox.LostFocus
        Try
            CustomerDataContext1.SubmitChanges()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

Private Sub CompanyNameTextBox_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CompanyNameTextBox.LostFocus
        Try
            CustomerDataContext1.SubmitChanges()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

Private Sub ContactNameTextBox_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ContactNameTextBox.LostFocus
        Try
            CustomerDataContext1.SubmitChanges()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim textBoxes = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
For Each txtbox In textBoxes
    AddHandler txtbox.LostFocus, AddressOf txtLostFocus
Next
```

one handler for all txtbox'es.

```
Private Sub txtLostFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

 Try
        CustomerDataContext1.SubmitChanges()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
End sub
```

Comment: Does this answer not suit you?

Comment: Looks great. Just what I was looking for. I just need to know where to place this code in the project? Sorry I'm a little new to .Net.

Comment: Place the first part in your Form_load of the form you will use it, and the second part wherever you like ;)

Comment: You are right. Soooo Cool. Works! I started to put the first part in the form_load, but txtLostFocus was undefined, because I hadn't put the 2nd part in the form code yet. Once I put the 2nd part down at the bottom of the form class, it worked. Awesome. Just what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?:

```
Private Sub "Your form"(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles 
MyBase.Load
    AddHandler CustomerIDTextBox.LostFocus, AddressOf DoStuff
    AddHandler CompanyNameTextBox.LostFocus, AddressOf DoStuff
    AddHandler ContactNameTextBox.LostFocus, AddressOf DoStuff
End Sub

Private Sub DoStuff(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Try
        CustomerDataContext1.SubmitChanges()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: This won't do. While I do know all the controls at design time, there will be many many text boxes spread out over a tabbed group control. Thus trying to get away from what you have proposed.